# Irreducibile iff closure is irreducible

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry

Let $f:\mathbb{P}^n \to \mathbb{P}^m$ be a morphism. Is $f(\mathbb{P}^n)$ irreducible?

More generally, let $X$ be a topological space and $Y\subset X$ a subset. If $\overline{Y}$ is irreducible, does this imply $Y$ is irreducible?

Comment: 1) the proof is more or less the same as $f(X)$ is connected if $X$ is connected. 2) Yes.

Comment: For the first question, I hope you also realize that $f(\mathbb{P}^n)$ is either $\mathbb{P}^n$ or a point.

Comment: @NicolasHemelsoet, Are you referring to the point set topology proof showing that the image of a connected space under a continuous map is connected? Also, could you please explain why (2) is true?

Comment: @Mohan That's what I am trying to show. What I have left to show is that $f(\mathbb{P}^n)$ is irreducible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $Y = F_1 \cup F_2$ where $F_i$ are proper closed subset of $Y$. Let $G_1, G_2$ the closure of $F_1, F_2$ in $\overline Y$. Then, $\overline Y = G_1 \cup G_2$, in particular $\overline Y$ is reducible. This shows that if $\overline Y$ is irreducible then $Y$ is irreducible.

Comment: Thank you. How do we know that $G_1$ and $G_2$ are proper closed subsets of $\overline{Y}$?